# Grunt tasks are not loading, get infinite loop

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I can't get my grunt watch, sass, concat, nor uglify to load properly.
This is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig ({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    watch: {
        files: ['src/*.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint']
    },

    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                [
                'src/*.css': 'main.scss',
                'widgets.css': 'widgets.scss'
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    concat: {
      js: {
        src: 'src/*.js',
        dest: 'src/build/concatenated.js'
      }
},


    uglify: {
  build: {
    src: 'src/build/concatenated.js',
    dest: 'src/build/concatenated.min.js'
  }
}

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
grunt.registerTask('concat',['concat','uglify']);

};
```

In my terminal, when I type in 'grunt' I get the error message:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I don't see an extra semi-colon listed anywhere. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files: {
         [
           'src/*.css': 'main.scss',
            'widgets.css': 'widgets.scss'
          ]
       }
```

should be

```
files: {
          'src/*.css': 'main.scss',
          'widgets.css': 'widgets.scss'
       }
```

Comment: Thanks @keshav. I'm able to run 'grunt watch' per your solution, however I still can't get 'grunt concat' to work. Any insight on this?

Comment: Can you provide details on the error you are getting with concat?

Comment: Try changing the name of the task from `concat` to something else.  `foo` would work perfectly fine to test

Comment: @keshav when I try running 'grunt concat' I get a blank output, and have to exit out by doing Control + C